# How to install nvidia proprietary drivers when using custom kernel?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 17.10

I am running Kubuntu 17.10, and I’m using the ACSO patch kernel, version 4.15.15 from https://queuecumber.gitlab.io/linux-acs-override/

I was able to get the nvidia drivers installed prior to installing this kernel, but after installing it all I get is a black screen.

I have tried removing and reinstalling them, and I have also tried the latest version from the nvidia ppa. Nothing seems to work. Everything is fine with the stock kernel, black screen with the ACSO kernel...I’m probably just missing something simple, but I’m out of ideas.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the output of `dkms status`

Comment: Running in terminal, I get no output at all.

Comment: Updated to 18.04 and the nvidia drivers still dont work, except now I get stuck in 1024x768 and the nvidia drivers will not load.